# Error: Found multiple <meta-data> elements

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I created an app (bundle: myApp.aab) (using cn1: Android build) and tried to upload it on google-console, but it was rejected with the following error:

*An error occurred while running bundletool build-apks on your uploaded App Bundle. Ensure that your App Bundle is valid by running bundletool build-apks locally and try again. Error: Found multiple  elements for key 'com.google.android.gms.version', expected at most one.*

When I decompiled AndroidManifest.xml (using bundletool.jar on myApp.aab) I noticed that the following line appears twice:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This is obviously the cause of the error described above. This line appears only once in the 'build hints' (in cn1-settings: key=android.xapplication).

I tried to delete this `<meta-data>` tag (in the 'build hints'), but during the build process it was automatically added.

So the problem is that cn1 automatically generates this tag twice in the AndroidManifest.xml during the build process, and therefore google-console generates an error during the upload of the myApp.aab file.

What can I do to avoid this problem ?

Comment: The line that you said appears twice seems to be missing. Can you edit your post and make sure it appears after editing? Also make sure to censor private information such as keys!

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't review the question  properly. Now I edited the question again. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Can you add the build hints you're using. The ones specific to android nothing else is needed. You can see them in `codenameone_settings.properties`. Everything starting with `codenameone.arg.and*` should be applicable. Also a list of the libraries you're using.  I see this value coming in from the ads option but I don't see it coming in twice.

Comment: I use this library: _AdMob Fullscreen Ads_. One build hint is: `codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>`. The second build hint is: `codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<activity android\:name\="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android\:configChanges\="keyboard|  ....etc ....." /><meta-data android\:name\="com.google.android.gms.version" android\:value\="@integer/google_play_services_version" /><activity android\:name\.... the first tag repeated! ..... />` .

Comment: One more remark, before the build process in cn1, the second build hint contained only the first <activity android> tag. After the build process, the <meta-data> tag was automatically added and the first tag was added again. I deleted <meta-data> tag (before the build), since I was trying to solve my problem: multiple `com.google.android.gms.version` .

Comment: Are you using maven or Ant? Try removing the build hint and the library just to verify that it is indeed the culprit (without uploading).

Comment: I use Ant, Netbeans ide + cn1 plugin. I removed the admob lib (as you suggested). So myApp.jar didn't contain the admob lib. I created the new myApp.aab, and the androidManifest containes again the problematic <meta-data > tag twice. It seams that the admob lib is not the culprit.

Comment: When you say to remove the build hint, do you mean the whole _android.xapplication_ hint, or just the <meta-data> tag in the value of the hint? I tried to remove just the <meta-data> tag, but the cn1-build automatically adds the tag again, so I can't remove it. Is there a way to edit this build hint (_xapplication_) and to remove the <meta-data> tag ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem specific to Ant since that system used a somewhat flawed approach of modifying the build hints to inject additional meta-data. As a workaround, try unzipping the fullscreen ads cn1lib and removing that hint from the properties file at the root. Then rezip it and replace the existing file.

Remove the build hint `android.xpermissions`. It will regenerate without the meta tag. That might workaround the problem.

Comment: Thank you Shai, I did as you suggested in your answer and it solved the problem. Now the <meta-data> tag appears only once in the AndroidManifest file. I removed only the <meta-data> part from the build-hint: _android.xapplication_ in the library: AdmobFullscreen.cn1lib (in the file: codenameone_library_appended.properties). Today I have successfully uploaded the myApp.aab bundle in the Google console. Thanks, this was a tough problem for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it was rough. You did handle it well. I suggest migrating to maven when you get the chance, I don't think the problem would have occurred with Maven.